# Sorting Objects By Biggest Attribute Value Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, jinja2

I am creating an application which will record Athletics events and points. Eventually I want to show on the screen the HOUSES (teams), points, and their overall position. The team with the highest number of points will be number one etc...

My model has a field `points` which will be updated as results are recorded. I want the model to auto-determine he position of the team based off of the other objects' points. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:
models.py

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    points = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)
    house_color = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default='red')
    position = models.IntegerField(default=4)


    def determine_position(self):
        all_houses_queryset = self.objects.all()
```

I've tried to get the index of an ordered queryset on the template but it threw a Value error.

Views.py

```
def dashboard(request):

    ordered_houses = House.objects.all().order_by('-points').values()
    context = {
        'houses': ordered_houses,
        'range': [1,2,3,4],
    }

    return render(request, 'core/index.html', context)
```

index.html
`{% for index, house in houses %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enumerate the items:

```
def dashboard(request):
    ordered_houses = enumerate(House.objects.order_by('-points'), 1)
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'houses': ordered_houses})
```

and work with:

```
{% for index, house in houses %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endfor %}
```

Please *don't* use values, it is a [*primitive obsession* antipattern <sup>[refactoring.guru]</sup>](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) and prevents exposing logic in the template, and following relations like `ForeignKey`s.

Comment: It works! However, the index starts from 0. Is there a way I can do 'index+1' ? The templating engine doesn't like that syntax.

Comment: @tinotendakanyoka: that is the `,1` at the end of the `enumerate(...)`

Comment: I'd omitted the ,1

Comment: @tinotendakanyoka: well the second parameter is the start of the index. So `-1` would start it at `-1`, it has to be an integer however, not a float, complex, etc.